# how to use pip in docker with openshift image ubi8-python:3.11

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, openshift

**I use this docker file**

```
FROM <my_enterprise_nexus_repository>:18444/ubi8-python:3.11
**strong text**
# Add application sources with correct permissions for OpenShift
USER 0
ADD src .
RUN chown -R 1001:0 ./
USER 1001

ENV ENABLE_PIPENV=True

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install -U "pip>=19.3.1" && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt 

# Run the application
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

I want to create an image for my python project with docker using the ubi8-python:3.11 source

It's not working, i don't know what to do

**When i run** `docker build -t sample_project --rm .`

**I have this error**

```
#10 [4/4] RUN pip install -U "pip>=19.3.1" &&     pip install -r requirements.txt
#10 0.198 /bin/sh: pip: command not found
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -U \"pip>=19.3.1\" &&     pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
------
 > [4/4] RUN pip install -U "pip>=19.3.1" &&     pip install -r requirements.txt:
0.198 /bin/sh: pip: command not found
------
Dockerfile:14
--------------------
  13 |     # Install the dependencies
  14 | >>> RUN pip install -U "pip>=19.3.1" && \
  15 | >>>     pip install -r requirements.txt
  16 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -U \"pip>=19.3.1\" &&     pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

I tried to add some `yum install python-pip` but iI have the same kind of error : `yum: command not found`

**how can I make this work?**

Comment: somewhere on Python web page should be file `get_pip.py` which can download and install  `pip`

Comment: you can try to use `python -m pip install ...` instead of `pip install ...`. OR maybe it needs `/full/path/to/pip`

Answer (score 0):

With the help of "furas", I found the solution

The command `whereis python` gives `/opt/python/bin/python3.11`

The command `wereis pip` gives `/opt/python/bin/pip3.11`

So i can use

`RUN  /opt/python/bin/pip3.11 install -r requirements.txt`

instead of

`RUN  pip install -r requirements.txt`